# Opencv Static Linking Gives Error

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Recently I build opencv as static library(by using BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF) while dynamic libraries are already there, but at different location. And when I build may program I am getting many error. I am using command line for compiling the code, and look like below.

```
g++ -static -I$(OpenCV_Static_Build)/include/opencv -L$(OpenCV_Static_Build)/lib/ -g -o binary  main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

The error look like,

```
grfmt_tiff.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11TiffEncoder12writeLibTiffERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x167): undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
window_gtk.cpp:(.text.cvNamedWindow+0x29d): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2.o): In function `uw_init_context_1':
(.text+0x22f8): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
```

Answer (score 1):

Those errors don't come from OpenCV (as one can tell from the function names) but from GLib and libpthread. Use the `-lglib-2.0 -lpthread` linker flags.

Comment: Hi I added that and pthread error has gone but still the other errors are there. Do I need to link more libraries?.

Comment: Still I am waiting answer which will solve my problem. Actually I am goggling and linking more libs, but still the error is increasing.